# Get insert_id() from one function to another

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Good Day!

I have a code when I click SUBMIT button, I will perform the two functions and insert the data into database with auto_increment ID.

```
public function insert1()
    {   
        $this->db->insert('db1');
        $id1 = $this->db->insert_id();

        return (isset($id1)) ? $id1 : FALSE;
    }

public function insert2()
        {   
                    $this->db->set('insert1_id', $id1);
            $this->db->insert('db2');
            $id2 = $this->db->insert_id();

            return (isset($id2)) ? $id2 : FALSE;
        }
```

What if in function `inser1()` in this code return (isset($id1)) ? $id21 : FALSE; if `$id1` `is set` and TRUE it will perform the `insert2()` function and I will get the `inserted id` and set this in column `insert1_id` from the function `insert2()`?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: you might have to set the var to global. But sounds like it would be better to merge the functions or create a new one to get around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would only call insert 2 and let it decide where to go.

```
public function insert1()
{   
    $this->db->insert('db1');
    $id1 = $this->db->insert_id();

    return (isset($id1)) ? $id1 : FALSE;
}

public function insert2()
{   
   $id1 = $this->insert1();
   if($id1 !== false)
   {
       $this->db->set('insert1_id', $id1);
       $this->db->insert('db2');
       $id2 = $this->db->insert_id();
   }


   return (isset($id2)) ? $id2 : FALSE;
}
```

Then just call insert2() and let it deal with insert 1.

Comment: did you forget to remove the original call to insert1() ?

Comment: how to avoid that problem? I think it insert what does the function insert1() have inside?

Comment: I'm sorry but do you mean by that?

Comment: yeah don't call insert1() only call insert2() it will then call insert1()

Comment: feel free to accept the answer if it worked for you :)

Comment: What if I set in many columns? How do I call only one column in second function?